# How to remove all new line characters from all tables/columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on exporting a database from SQL Server to Snowflake and I have ran into an issue where we have and unknown number of columns that have user comments and have new line characters in them. The problem is the database has over 280 tables and I do not want to go through each table manually. I was wondering if there was a way to automate this.

I am currently using SSIS to export the data and just doing a select replace on the columns that I find have the newline character.

I have also used this script as well:

```
declare @NewLine char(2) set @NewLine=char(13)+char(10) update Projects set [PR_ITComment] =Replace([PR_ITComment] , @NewLine,'') WHERE [PR_ITComment] like '%' +@NewLine +'%'
```

Comment: It is going to be horribly slow to do this with a dynamic script on 280 tables. You are essentially saying you want to do this replace on every column of every row in every table. Or is it always just the column named PR_ITComment? And does it exist on every single table or do you need to only update tables that have that column name?

Comment: Performance and amount of time it takes to run is not a problem. So yes, I am looking for a dynamic script as we don't know exactly which columns have this problem so a script that goes through every column on every table is what I am looking for.

Comment: Btw, how do you export the data? If you can export to CSV-with-quotes, then I believe Snowflake should load it including the new lines.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski I originally had two problems one was the new lines and second was the comma as a delimiter wasn't unique enough. Also Snowflake is set to see any new line as a new row.

Comment: There's a way to do it - I posted a richer answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to Sean Lange's answer, but it resolves to one update per table instead of one update per column.

```
--declare @schema nvarchar(256) = 'dbo';
--declare @table  nvarchar(256) = 'table';
declare @sql    nvarchar(max) = '';

  set @sql += (select 'update '+t.table_schema+'.'+t.table_name+' set ' +stuff(
    ( select ', ['+i.column_name +']=replace(replace(['+i.column_name+'],char(10),''''),char(13),'''')'+char(10) 
        from information_schema.columns i 
        where i.table_schema=t.table_schema 
          and i.table_name=t.table_name 
          and i.data_type in ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext') 
        order by i.ordinal_position 
        for xml path('')),1,1,'')+';'+char(10)
    from information_schema.tables t
    where t.table_type='base table' 
      --and t.table_schema = @schema
      --and t.table_name   = @table
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')

  --print @sql
  select @sql
  --exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim and Sean Lange this has gotten me on the right track

Comment: One other question when I run this script it looks like it doesn't print out all the update statements as it looks like the last statement is cut off what is limiting this?

Comment: @unreal `print` has a limit of 4000/8000 characters. edited the answer to use `select`. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Print/63240/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to tackle this. This leverages dynamic sql so you don't have to resort to looping. You may want to tweak this a little bit to suit your needs. You might add another predicate to prevent certain tables or that sort of thing from the list. The way this works is that is creates a quite large number of update statements. Then you simply execute the massive string.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'Update ' + quotename(t.name) + ' set ' + quotename(c.name) + ' = replace(Replace(' + quotename(c.name) + ', char(10), ''''), char(13), '''');' 
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.systypes st on st.xtype = c.system_type_id
where st.name in ('text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar')

select @SQL

--Once you are comfortable with the output you can uncomment the line below to actually run this.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to export the data using quotes (which is the standard CSV way), Snowflake can simply load data with new lines. You can use escaping as well, but quoting is better.

Example file with 3 rows

```
$ cat data.csv
1,"a",b
2,c,"d1
d2"
3,"e1,e2,
e3",f
```

Example SQL and output:

```
create or replace table x(nr int, a string, b string);
put file://data.csv @%x;
copy into x file_format = (field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"');
select * from x;
----+--------+----+
 NR |   A    | B  |
----+--------+----+
 1  | a      | b  |
 2  | c      | d1 |
    |        | d2 |
 3  | e1,e2, | f  |
    | e3     |    |
----+--------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while exporting data to excel.
You can replace char(13) and char(10) Using ''. That will work.

It's simple replace in your "Execure SQL" task query or SP of SSIS. Or you can use it in update statement to update records forever.